# Why does my Nexus 6P's "Show CPU Usage" option only show com.android.systemui (and system apps)?

Tags: nexus-6p, developer-options

[image: screenshot of overlay]

It only ever shows `com.android.systemui` and other system apps. Here I'm loading a complex page:

[image: overlay not showing chrome when loading complex page]

Comment: Are you using a custom ROM? I'm getting the same on my Moto X 2013 but only on Marshmallow custom ROMs.

Comment: Yup, 100% stock.