# What part of Android is responsible for reporting how much battery an app uses?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, battery

In Android Marshmallow (and maybe earlier versions), you can go to App Info and see how much battery an app has used. If you click into it, it shows much how much CPU it's used as well as keep awake and network usage. The last line on the view shows "Computed power usage".

What part of the OS calculates this power usage? If "Computed power usage" is coming up as 0-1mAh regardless of usage, where would a developer go to fix it?

Comment: Some background for this question: In many of the MM custom ROMs I've used, there's some issue with battery/CPU usage reporting. None of the apps are being listed in the battery usage screen and none of them are being listed in the CPU usage. The behavior is detailed by someone else here https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/148600/why-does-my-nexus-6ps-show-cpu-usage-option-only-show-com-android-systemui-a

Comment: I can't see how this knowledge would be useful to anyone but a ROM developer.

Comment: @MatthewRead It may not be useful, but in my opinion this is an interesting question for those who don't trust said values, or for mere curiosity as well. Not a strictly development centric question, I think.

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate question because the other post's answer only speaks of Android generally. My question is asking specifically which part (bootloader, kernel, some part of system) of Android is responsible for that. I'm not an Android developer but I am a developer and if someone who knows better can point me to the right direction, I could investigate some repos.

Comment: @beeshyams I don't think it can be a duplicate, because the accepted answer to the other question doesn't answer this question at all.

Comment: @DanHulme: Agreed.  It explains partly how but doesn't answer this. I was in a hurry. Will retract closure and upvote the question

Comment: The strange thing is that GSam Battery Monitor seemingly correctly reports battery usage by apps...